cannot install "certbot": Post "https://api.snapcraft.io/v2/snaps/refresh": Method Not Allowed
I am trying to install certbot through snap on a vps with Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS and getting the following error:
$ sudo snap install --classic certbot
error: cannot install "certbot": Post "https://api.snapcraft.io/v2/snaps/refresh": Method Not Allowed

I have checked snapd status through systemctl status snapd.service and it is running (active). Also tried to install core but getting similar error:
$ sudo snap install core
error: cannot install "core": Post "https://api.snapcraft.io/v2/snaps/refresh": Moved Permanently

Any guidance to fix the issue would be much appreciated.
